# Filter Search AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I want to filter in search my catalogs `json`, but my code doesn't work, here is code :

```
    <input type="text" style="width:275px;margin-top:5px;" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-rounded" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="search">

  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="cui-ecommerce--catalog">
                <div class="row">
                    <div ng-repeat="(name, text) in textures | filter:search">
                        <div ng-repeat="url in text">
                            <div>
                              {{url.url}}
                                <a href="javascript: void(0);" style="cursor:default;">
                                    <img ng-src="{{url.url }}" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/30nyExfhnLWy35p906CJ?p=preview

Thanks for answers in advance!!!

Comment: Your plunkr is not working.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Here : https://plnkr.co/edit/M4pB48WNej1hh13l0ILT?p=preview is working, i deleted "filter:search" after ng-repeat, because this gives error, and this is my question, how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this alternative approach:

```
  <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cui-ecommerce--catalog">
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-repeat="(name, text) in textures">
                    <div ng-if="url.url.indexOf(search||'')>-1" ng-repeat="url in text" >
                        <div>
                          {{url.url}}
                            <a href="javascript: void(0);" style="cursor:default;">
                                <img ng-src="{{url.url }}" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/hxfgKziEAXHJeGjcmg9z?p=preview